How to do pooled meta analysis of single arm studies with continous data (pre-post intervention) in R?
I tried to do meta analysis of single arm studies (without control) using R studio, but I still can't find how to do the pooled analysis. I only have the mean and SD from pre treatment and mean with SD after weeks of treatment. Can I do pooled meta analysis of the single arm studies with continous data from pre and post intervention in R studio?

Does this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44541/meta-analysis-in-r-of-pre-post-treatment-design-studies?rq=1 help?

Thanks for your response, can I use that in single-arm meta-analysis? I only pooled one outcome of the studies in my meta-analysis, can I still use the coding there?
